# why this site feature is not activated when I create a new site by my custom web template?

Tags: web-template, onet

I am using sharepoint 2010 and vs2010.

I have created a custom webtemplates and begin from a copy of a teamsite. In my onet.xml I see the following site feature elements:

```
<SiteFeatures>
    <!-- BasicWebParts Feature -->
    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-1C5E-4A24-B310-BA51C3EB7A57" />
    <!-- Three-state Workflow Feature -->
    <Feature ID="FDE5D850-671E-4143-950A-87B473922DC7" />
  </SiteFeatures>
```

I created a new site collection from the site template "publish site"
I deployed my custom web template to this site collection.
I create a new site and select my custom web template.
I got some error: "the site template requires that the feature fde5d850-671e-4143-950a-87b473922dc7      be activated in the site collection"

When I go to the site collection features and enable this feature "Three-state workflow : fde5d850-671e-4143-950a-87b473922dc7" it works.

But I dont understand, why I need to do this manual?? In my onet.xml of my custom web template I have declare this feature to be activated in the sitefeature element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onet.xml file is divided into two parts, first is the "SiteFeatures" and the second called "WebFeatures". The "SiteFeatures" Section that holds the site features starts activating all the features **only** when creating a site collection.
The "WebFeatures" Section that holds the web features starts activating all the web scoped features **only** when creating a site (like you tried).

The solution is to trigger the Site collection scoped feature using web scoped feature.

The steps are:

**A)** Create an empty web scoped feature and in the "FeatureActivated" event add the following code.

```
  public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                //Ensure that scope is correctly set
                if (properties.Feature.Parent is SPWeb)
                {
                    SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;


                    foreach (SPFeatureProperty property in properties.Feature.Properties)
                    {
                        Guid featureGuid = new Guid(property.Value);
                        //Verify feature status
                        SPFeature feature = web.Site.Features[featureGuid];
                        if (feature == null)
                        {
                            //Activate site collection scoped feature, if requested and not currently activated
                            web.Site.Features.Add(featureGuid);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
        }
```

**B)** In the onet.xml file in the "WebFeature" Node add the following xml

```
 <WebFeatures>
       <!-- Custom Site collection scoped feature activation -->
        <Feature ID="YourEmptyFeatureGuid">
          <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="SiteScopedGUID" Value="FDE5D850-671E-4143-950A-87B473922DC7"/>
          </Properties>
        </Feature>
 </WebFeatures>
```

- In the Feature ID element add your empty feature's ID
- In the Property Key="SiteScopedGUID" element in the value add the site collection feature id that you want to activate.

That's it. deploy your solution and it should work.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I found your blog post on this subject at http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/sharepoint-cant-activate-site-collection-feature-when-creating-new-site-from-a-custom-web-template-aspx/ and it was very helpful